# gazebo import robot gives error

Tags: simulator, gazebo, simulation

I'm trying to import the tutorial robot given at [this link](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_robot&cat=build_robot)

However this gives the following error:

```
Error [Param.cc:181] Unable to set value [1,0471975511965976] for key[horizontal_fov]
Error [Param.cc:181] Unable to set value [0,100000001] for key[near]
Error [parser_urdf.cc:2635] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
Error [parser.cc:278] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error [parser_urdf.cc:2635] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
Error [parser.cc:278] parse as old deprecated model file failed.


Error [parser.cc:278] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
```

This sugest something is wrong with parsing but does not actually point towards any line of my code (the example is only 103 lines long).

```
    <link name='chassis'>
      <pose>0 0 .1 0 0 0</pose>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>.4 .2 .1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <visual name='visual'>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>.4 .2 .1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </visual>

      <collision name='caster_collision'>
        <pose>-0.15 0 -0.05 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <sphere>
          <radius>.05</radius>
        </sphere>
      </geometry>

      <surface>
        <friction>
          <ode>
            <mu>0</mu>
            <mu2>0</mu2>
            <slip1>1.0</slip1>
            <slip2>1.0</slip2>
          </ode>
        </friction>
      </surface>
    </collision>

    <visual name='caster_visual'>
      <pose>-0.15 0 -0.05 0 0 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <sphere>
          <radius>.05</radius>
        </sphere>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <link name="left_wheel">
    <pose>0.1 0.13 0.1 0 1.5707 1.5707</pose>
    <collision name="collision">
      <geometry>
        <cylinder>
          <radius>.1</radius>
          <length>.05</length>
        </cylinder>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual">
      <geometry>
        <cylinder>
          <radius>.1</radius>
          <length>.05</length>
        </cylinder>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <link name="right_wheel">
    <pose>0.1 -0.13 0.1 0 1.5707 1.5707</pose>
    <collision name="collision">
      <geometry>
        <cylinder>
          <radius>.1</radius>
          <length>.05</length>
        </cylinder>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual">
      <geometry>
        <cylinder>
          <radius>.1</radius>
          <length>.05</length>
        </cylinder>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <joint type="revolute" name="left_wheel_hinge">
    <pose>0 0 -0.03 0 0 0</pose>
    <child>left_wheel</child>
    <parent>chassis</parent>
    <axis>
      <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
    </axis>
  </joint>

  <joint type="revolute" name="right_wheel_hinge">
    <pose>0 0 0.03 0 0 0</pose>
    <child>right_wheel</child>
    <parent>chassis</parent>
    <axis>
      <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
    </axis>
  </joint>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

This is on ubuntu 14.04. Is there any hint at what I'm doing wrong or what information can I provide to better come to a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I should just have looked better at the tutorial as I missed a few lines of code.

Comment: It would be better to include what code is missing, in case somebody else in the future comes across this question!

Answer (score 0):

For someone who will investigate this issue.

If you created a model with two `link` but without `joint` between them, you will get parse issue:

```
Error [parser_urdf.cc:XXXX] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
Error [parser.cc:XXX] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
```